# Emirates Dubai Connect - which hotel?

Tags: usa, air-travel, layovers, dubai, emirates

I have been offered Dubai Connect by Emirates for a complimentary layover in Dubai. My first leg of journey till Dubai is in Economy Class and from Dubai to USA is business class. Does anyone have any idea which hotel would they be offering for this layover?

Answer (score 1):

The [terms and conditions for Dubai Connect](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/dubai-international-airport/dubai-connect-conditions.aspx) lists the hotels they normally use:

> The accommodation provided will be in the Copthorne Hotel Dubai, the Le Méridien Airport Hotel Dubai, the Arabian Park Hotel Dubai or another alternative at the discretion of Emirates. We do not make any guarantee as to the accommodation allocated to you in any manner (e.g. facilities, hotel, location, star rating).

Comment: last time i got Copthorne Hotel but since it was complete economy ticket.This time till dubai its economy and dubai  to usa is business so i was wondering if there could be a better hotel

Comment: Possibly so. It certainly sounds like business and first get better hotels. Maybe Emirates can tell you which hotel you will stay in, if you call them.